# Windows form C# Bitmap Image

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I am getting this error when I try to put a image in a Bitmap on Windows Form ...

```
class PlayerPlane
    {
        private Bitmap playerPlaneImg { get; set; }
        private Graphics graphics { get; set; }
        private int playerLife { get; set; }
        private int playerSpeed { get; set; }

    public PlayerPlane()
    {
        playerPlaneImg = new Bitmap("Back.bmp"); //ERROR HERE ?!
        graphics.DrawImage(playerPlaneImg, 60, 10);
    }

}
```

The image is located in my project: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfTrH.png ....

Comment: Put image in the same location with exe.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/12eksz

Comment: The image is in the same area with the class

Comment: Can you please add the error message to the comment section..?  Just  write out the error message and code..  Thanks..  Or place on Github if you have it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From *[`Bitmap Constructor (String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f.aspx)*

```
Parameters
filename
Type: System.String
The bitmap file name and path.
```

I think you can try with *full path* of image. Or try like;

```
playerPlaneImg = new Bitmap("~/Back.bmp");
```

Comment: Soner Gönül
I have entered the full path to the picture and but I get this error now which is normal because I don't know how to set the Graphic constructor
http://i.imgur.com/tKgt2l4.png
I have seen codes vere the use Graphics.DrawImage( ... , ... , ..); 
What should I do now ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f.aspx):

> The file name and path can be relative to the application or an absolute path. Use this constructor to open images with the following file formats: BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPG, PNG and TIFF. For more information about supported formats, see Types of Bitmaps. The file remains locked until the Bitmap is disposed.

You could either place the absolute path of your image or the relative path of your image based on the executable part of your program.

Comment: Even if I put the absolute path to the image it still wont work ...
This is the error 
http://i.imgur.com/Sz6levY.png
And I have been reading all day MSDN official help ... :(

Comment: do you get the same error when placing the absolute path? can you update your code above with either your absolute or relative path?

Answer (score 0):

change your back image an copy output directory option to copy always or copy if newer then you can use relative path. for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPJss.png

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bmp = new Bitmap("Bitmap1.bmp");
        }
    }
}
```